# Can I ask about a perceived structural problem with another Stack Exchange site?

Tags: discussion, stack-exchange

Can I post a question here on Meta Stack Exchange about a large problem regarding the structural organization of a particular Stack Exchange? I want to know this first before preparing the detailed question with diagrams. Overall, I believe that I have found a major problem with one of the Stack Exchanges that needs to be solved.

Comment: You really should post such a thing on the meta of said stack exchange.

Comment: Don't post it here. Post it on the meta for that site.

Comment: Alright, however the moderators are strict about adhering to their posting rules and it most certainly would be against their stack exchange rules...

Comment: @gordon50 Each site has it's own meta so you'd post it there if the issue is specific to that site.

Comment: Thanks I will look for it at Beta Health.

Comment: @Catija No, the first rule of Meta Stack Exchange is: No Fight Club References.

Comment: @Zibbobz Figures. I don't even *like* Fight Club.

Comment: Sup guize was passing by when I smelled the intense possibility of major drama and epic butthurt and was drawn to this question.  What's happening hurr?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

That depends.

- If your question is about the overall structure of SE across multiple sites, it is a question about SE and should be posted on Meta.SE
- If your question is specific to the SE site and how it is organized, it should be posted on that site's own Meta Page.

Not knowing what your question is, I cannot tell you whether or not it is appropriate for this site or for the Meta site.

What you *can* do is post the question on whichever site you believe it is best suited for, and if it would be better suited for the other site's meta page, it will be migrated to that site by a moderator.  So even if you post it on the wrong site, your question will not be lost!

However, whatever you do please do **not** post it on both Meta sites - this is frowned upon as it requires one question to be closed, and may cause some confusion about which one should be closed.  Cross-site posting is generally frowned upon for this reason, so please only post your question on one site or the other.